# Dirichlet/multinomial dirichlet model with autocorrelation

Tags: autocorrelation, autoregressive, dirichlet-distribution, multinomial-dirichlet-distribution

I need to estimate an inferential statistical model of a variable that is a set of 8 proportions that sum to 1. The data repeat for 25 years and the series is an AR1 process. Is there a statistical software (R, STATA, or a Python library) that can estimate a dirichlet/multinomial dirichlet model and also correct the standard errors for AR1 serial correlation? It looks like dirifit in STATA and VGAM in R do not have a way to correct for AR1 serial correlation. Is there any other package/library that I am missing?

Comment: Have you considered a Bayesian model in [rstan](https://mc-stan.org/users/interfaces/rstan)?  You can set up the exact data process that you want.

Comment: I'll check it out! Thanks for the tip.